# How do I load part of a JSON file and gulp inject it into my js file?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to inject a part of my config.JSON file into my javascript file.

For example, here is my `appconfig.json`:

```
{
  "prod": {
    "CONSTANTs" : {
      "url1": "https://someurl",
      "url2": "https://anotherurl",      
    }
  },
  "qa":{
    "CONSTANTS" : {
      "url1": "http://differenturl",
      "url2": "https://differenturl2",
    }
  }
}
```

I want the prod values for my `gulp build-prod` job and the qa values for my `gulp build-qa`.

How do I do that using gulp?

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did to inject a part of a JSON file into a variable in my js file:

The secret sauce is `gulp-template` and `fs`

Code:
`gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var template = require('gulp-template');
var fs = require('fs');

var configJSON = fs.readFileSync('appconfig.json');
var configDict = JSON.parse(configJSON).prod;

gulp.task('myConstants', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/background.js')
    .pipe(template({myConfig: JSON.stringify(configDict)}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

My js file:
`background.js`

```
var config = <%= myConfig %>
```